# My Ajax Wont redirect when I get callback from localstorage

Tags: jquery, ajax, cordova

I'm trying to save the my return data from an ajax login system (in cordova) and access the data in a separate page. It doesn't work. The redirect doesn't happen, and the return data doesn't work! Please please please help!

Index.html

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi">
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("form").submit(function () {

                var uname = document.getElementById("username").value;
                var pword = document.getElementById("password").value;
                var postData = {
                    username: uname,
                    password: pword
                };

                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://www.yellowcabsavannah.com/test.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: postData,
                    async: false,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (data) {

                        var ReturnMessage = data.message;

                        localStorage.setItem('message', ReturnMessage);

                        window.location = "map.html";
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="">
        <input type='text' id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username">
        <br>
        <input type='password' id="password" name="password" placeholder="password">
        <br>
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Login">
    </form>
</body>
```

test.php

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$mysql_host = "";
$mysql_database = "";
$mysql_user = "";
$mysql_password = "";
$conn=mysql_connect($mysql_host,$mysql_user,$mysql_password);
mysql_select_db($mysql_database);

$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password =  mysql_real_escape_string(MD5($_POST['password']));

$sql="SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE uname = '$username' AND pword = '$password'";

$r = mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $name = $row["name"];
}

if(mysql_num_rows($r) != 1){
    echo json_encode(array("message" => "Nope! Wrong Login!"));
}
if(mysql_num_rows($r) == 1)
{
    echo json_encode(array("message" => $name));
}
?>
```

map.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
 Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
 or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
 distributed with this work for additional information
 regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
 to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
 "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
 with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

 http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

 Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
 software distributed under the License is distributed on an
 "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
 KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
 specific language governing permissions and limitations
 under the License.
 -->
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <title>Hello World</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.3.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            app.initialize();
            document.addEventListener()
            {
                ‘deviceready’, onDeviceReady, false);
            }
            function onDeviceReady()
            {
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    var RetMessage = localStorage.getItem('message');
                    alert(RetMessage);
                });
            }
            </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Your on map.html</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: if you put alert('Hello'); in the callback does it work ?

Comment: Actually, I got the redirect to work. I used document.location.href="map.html";

Comment: Now, I need help validating the user in the php. No matter what I enter, the php is returning a wrong value

Comment: does it reach the PHP page & BTW I don't think so

Comment: I'm testing it now. It does. I just keep getting back a value that says the login is wrong

Comment: then check your data print it

Comment: That's good glad that I could help , please don't use mysql_* funcitons they are deprecated

Comment: Thank you. Also, how would I not use mysql functions?

Comment: mysqli functions and PDO google them :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
window.localStorage.setItem('message', ReturnMessage);
```

instead of

```
localStorage.setItem('message', ReturnMessage);
```

and

```
$.mobile.changePage("map.html");
```

instead of

```
window.location = "map.html";
```